# Google Maps - places want to go

Tags: google-maps

On my phone, I have several places marked under "want to go". When I log into my account on another device, those places are not there.

How can I see the "want to go" on my phone and on my computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find it under **Your places** > **SAVED** > **Want to go**

[image]

Comment: The ones I have saved on my phone do not appear on my computer. That is my problem,

Comment: make sure you sync your acc otherwise, the data saved in your mobile device are only local

Comment: Sync is turned on - on the device and the computer

Comment: @James Your last comment here is that sync is already turned on, yet you have marked this as the correct answer? So what was the solution then?